# I'm Trying to figure out the timing of the iOS Keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

So here is the situation of the timing. I have a UILabel that I want to update every time the keyboard updates a UITextField. I have two UITextFields but only one is ever the first responder so don't worry about there being two I have them for back end purposes. The problem is the timing from the UILabel updating and the UITextField delegate function

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;˚
```

The replacement string doesn't get added until YES is returned to by the above function. I need to update my labels either after this function is called or during this function. I can't seem to figure out how it will work. The UILabel is always one character behind. Below is my code in general for this section.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if([self.hiddenTextFieldForTimeMinutes.text length] == 2 && [self.hiddenTextFieldForTime.text length] == 2 && ![string isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        return NO;
    }

    [self syncTextFieldsMinutesAndHours: string];

    // This returns the default Yes;
    return YES;
}

- (void) setAccessoryLabel: (NSString *) hourString minutesString: (NSString *) minuteString
{
    timeAccessoryLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", hourString, minuteString];
}

- (void) syncTextFieldsMinutesAndHours: (NSString *) string
{
    // These are the textFields
    NSMutableString *hoursString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"%@", self.hiddenTextFieldForTime.text];
    NSMutableString *minutesString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"%@", self.hiddenTextFieldForTimeMinutes.text];

    if([self.hiddenTextFieldForTimeMinutes.text length] == 2 && ![string isEqualToString: @""])
    {
        [hoursString appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [minutesString characterAtIndex:0]]];
        [self.hiddenTextFieldForTime setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", hoursString]];
        [self.hiddenTextFieldForTimeMinutes setText: [self.hiddenTextFieldForTimeMinutes.text substringFromIndex:1]];
    } else if([self.hiddenTextFieldForTimeMinutes.text length] == 2 && [string isEqualToString: @""])
      {
          // Hours has nothing in it
          if([hoursString length] == 0)
          {
              return;
          } else if([hoursString length] == 1)
            {
                // Since the timing of the add and remove of the string is done by return of the delegate we append the string to the beginning first then return.
                [self.hiddenTextFieldForTimeMinutes setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%@", [self.hiddenTextFieldForTime.text characterAtIndex:0], self.hiddenTextFieldForTimeMinutes.text]];
                [self.hiddenTextFieldForTime setText:@""];

            } else if ([hoursString length] == 2)
              {
                  // Since the timing of the add and remove of the string is done by return of the delegate we append the string to the beginning first then return.
                  [self.hiddenTextFieldForTimeMinutes setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%@", [self.hiddenTextFieldForTime.text characterAtIndex:1], self.hiddenTextFieldForTimeMinutes.text]];
                  [self.hiddenTextFieldForTime setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [self.hiddenTextFieldForTime.text characterAtIndex:0]]];
              }
      }

    [self setAccessoryLabel: self.hiddenTextFieldForTime.text minutesString:self.hiddenTextFieldForTimeMinutes.text];
}
```

Comment: "The replacement string doesn't get added until YES is returned to by the above function." Could you clarify that - I see you don't appear to be manipulating the label whenever you return NO from that method, so I'm not sure if this is a statement of your problem or a statement of your requirement. If the latter, could you explain a bit more about your problem?

Comment: Why are you updating the label through `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`? Why not update the label when the text field actually changes? Why not update the label based on the full text of the text field?

Comment: You also aren't dealing with the range at all. What if a user selects and replaces character(s)?

Comment: Can you explain what this function is for? Using "hidden text fields" may not be the best way to do it. I'm trying to follow your code and it looks like if the right strings are not in the text fields, you do nothing. But, if the correct strings are in the text fields, you then modify the contents of the text fields. Maybe we can help suggest a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. The text of the textField in `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`  will still have the old value, because it only gets changed after you answered yes to the question if the text **should** change.

You have two options.

create the `NSString` that your textField will have after you returned YES yourself:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if([self.hiddenTextFieldForTimeMinutes.text length] == 2 && [self.hiddenTextFieldForTime.text length] == 2 && ![string isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        return NO;
    }

    NSString *realString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    [self syncTextFieldsMinutesAndHours: realString];

    // This returns the default Yes;
    return YES;
}
```

or add a IBAction that gets called after the editing took place:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // your viewDidLoad implementation
    [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}

- (IBAction)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)sender {
    [self syncTextFieldsMinutesAndHours: sender.text];
}
```

Comment: I like this answer. I don't think mine is what you're looking for, but thanks for the upvote @MichaelChoi

Answer (score 1):

After mulling for a few minutes, this could be a run loop issue. Try adding this before you call the method to update your UILabel:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate: [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 0.01]];
//update label
[self updateLabelWithText:foo andText:bar];
```

Or try using GCD:

```
dispatch_queue_t main_queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    dispatch_async(main_queue, ^{
    // UI Updates here
    [self updateLabel...];
    });
});
```